# How much space Binding element going to take?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Following code from my studentDeatils.xaml page. I have

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="StudentDetails">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="40">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="2,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentRegNo, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="85,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="175,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TWD, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="365,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

 <TextBlock x:Name="totalstudents" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="247" />
```

I send data to to .xaml page using following code from studentDeatils.xaml.cs. Here StudentDetailsViewer class used to show binding fileds.

```
foreach (var stu in Studentdetails)
                {
                    this.StudentsheetItems.Add(new StudentDetailsViewer()
                    {
                        StudentName = stu.StudentName,
                        StudentRegNo = stu.StudentRegNo,
                        Address= stu.Address,
                        TWD = stu.TWD

                    });

                };

                StudentDetails.ItemsSource = StudentsheetItems;
```

I want to view TextBlock(x:Name="totalstudents") after binding list. How to get to know how much space binding Listbox going to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont think about Height, let XAML do it for you.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.Rowdefinitions>
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="StudentDetails">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="40">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="2,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentRegNo, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="85,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="175,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TWD, StringFormat='t'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="365,0,12,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

 <TextBlock x:Name="totalstudents" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="247" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's not work to me. I add the above listbox into <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1"><Grid> and add the text block into <Grid Grid.Row="2"><Grid>. But Not works...

Comment: Hi @Johannes Wanzek... If I using Grid.Row="0" and Grid.Row="1" page going to separated by half. I want to visible that textbox according to that listbox size.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the Grid closing Tag. Row 0 takes as much space as available and Grid 1 takes as much space as it needs. Try again. Ist should work.